# Object Creation with System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpressions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have the following get/setter object

```
internal class Some_Element<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public T prop1 { get; set; }
    public T prop2 { get; set; }
    public T prop3 { get; set; }
    public T prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to see how I can create an object on the fly using a createobject function
like this

```
CreateObject<Some_Element<int>>(o => (o.prop1 == o.prop2) && (o.prop3 < o.prop4))
```

The function creates a `Some_Element` object such that it meets the conditions in the function arguments. is there a way I can do that? I am new to BinaryExpressions any assistance would be a great segway for me to explore Expressions further

Also, how do I check the conditions such that I can't pass a contradiction?

for example ->

```
CreateObject<Some_Element<int>>(o => (o.prop1 == o.prop2) && (o.prop1 < o.prop2))
```

Comment: Are you referring to some kind of existing third-party library with this functionality and how to use it, or are you asking how to implement such a thing yourself? The latter is a very broad question, arguably too broad. Allowing completely freeform expressions would practically mandate incorporating a constraint solver. If you're doing this sort of thing for testing purposes, take a look at how Moq (and other mocking libraries) approach this.

Comment: What is `CreateObject<T>` in this context? And by "`BinaryExpression`" are you referring to `System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression`? If so, I don't see how that's relevant to creating objects...

Comment: Also, this post sounds like an X/Y Problem in that you're wanting to use generics and `System.Linq.Expressions` for the purposes of _comparing something_ - which doesn't add-up.

Comment: yes I mean System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression, through my research I thought that was the most appropriate one, if there is another way to create an object meeting the requirements of the function arguments with random values for the properties, I am open to it

Comment: @Adhil `BinaryExpression` has _absolutely nothing_ to do with creating objects though... In fact, I don't see how `System.Linq.Expressions` (SLE) is useful at all here: SLE is intended for things like runtime SQL generation from a C# expression, which I don't think is relevant to whatever problem you're trying to solve (which you still haven't actually stated).

Comment: @Dai Actually I am creating test cases and I need to test all IComparable Datatypes, I need to create an object whose properties can be any type

Comment: SO is not a site for library recommendations. This problem would be hard if not impossible to solve in general, and difficult enough if it's supposed to yield non-trivial results. Without specific logic for `int`, for example, it's impossible to know how to generate two values such that `x < y`. For general `IComparable` implementations it's *literally* impossible, as a `Compare` function can implement arbitrary logic, making this equivalent to the halting problem. Certainly you can write "something" that works "in a lot of cases", but just supplying relevant test cases yourself is far easier.

Comment: @Adhil What do you mean by "test all IComparable datatypes"? (and there really isn't any need to write your own test-cases for .NET's in-box types: Microsoft wouldn't publish them unless they were already well-tested themselves).

Comment: ok forget the generics, is there a way I can create an object (whose properties are all ints) with random values such that it meets the condition set in the `CreateObject` function arguments?

Comment: Certainly. Take an `Expression<Func<MyType, bool>>` argument, peel apart the `BinaryExpression` body yourself (recursively), check the conditions, and implement logic for generating values that meet the criteria. It's the latter bit that's challenging, and I'd argue beyond the scope of an answer. (If you're fine with a method that loops infinitely if you pass a contradiction, for example, it's not that hard -- but if you're not, you essentially are asking for a solution to an arbitrary satisfiability problem, which is NP-complete and better done with a dedicated solver.)

Comment: I think the answer has to be 1) Find a constraint solver which fits you needs, 2) Parse the expression to generate the inputs required by the constraint solver

Comment: @canton7 any good material on that?